# Use depth-first search to produce a spanning tree for the given simple graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Use depth-first search to produce a spanning tree for the given simple graph. Choose $a$ as the root of this spanning tree.

[image]

Here is answer and I am not sure  whether is correct or not

[image]

Can anyone verify my answer

Comment: Looks right to me.  Of course, there are many possibilities, but this is a DFS-tree.

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid spanning tree, but not a DFS tree.

Hint 1:

> In a DFS, a vertex is not marked “finished” until all of its neighbours have been examined.

Hint 2:

> Every edge of an undirected graph is either a “tree edge” (an edge occurring in the DFS tree) or a “back edge” (an edge going from a vertex in the DFS tree to one if its ancestors).

Hint 3:

> Look at the edge between $g$ and $h$, or the edge between $m$ and $i$.